# Unable to download file from FTP server using URLConnection having spaces in path

Tags: android, urlconnection

I'm Unable to download file from FTP server using URLConnection having spaces in pat

```
String s = "ftp://username:password@ftpclient:21/AAB BBC/hhhh 0001.jpg";
```

URL u = new URL(s);
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(uc.getOutputStream());

Dont want FTP client solution.

Using URLencoder getting 550 error file not found.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache commons Library ? If so , use this code

```
try {
    FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(desFilePath);;
    status = FTP_object.retrieveFile(srcFilePath, desFileStream);
    desFileStream.close();

    return status;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "download failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have spaces in your URL itself per [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) section 2.2  Run it through the URL Encode method to encode it:

```
String s = "ftp://username:password@ftpclient:21/AAB BBC/hhhh 0001.jpg";
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(s,"UTF-8");
```

I realize you said you were already doing the encoding, but that returned a 550 error.  I didn't see the encoding so am just mentioning it should be needed.

I would really try this from a browser and see if you can get to it.  I would also dump out the URL it is using and try that from a browser (or wget, curl, whatever you have handy).  The 550 is listed as being a "permission" problem, not file not found, so I'm a little surprised at that, but that may be the short code and come up as an error to prevent people from poking around testing user/password combinations.  Hard to say.

The other question I have for you is that you mention you don't want a client solution, but you seem to be writing a client not a server.  You're going to port 21, which is the default FTP port for a server.

I would try various combinations of the encoding and see if maybe you're not encoding everything...you should encode the url path.  Does the password have any funky characters in it?

Testing from the browser directly will give you a lot of insight.